# hide toolbar when collapsing collapsingtoobarlayout

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

What I am trying to achieve is hide the collapsingtoolbarlayout when scrolling my recyclerview and collapse the maintoolbar if scrolled further. but I can achieve only upto this [http://i.imgur.com/t6wTW5H.gif](https://i.imgur.com/t6wTW5H.gif).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/id_toolbar_container"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sample"/>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So I cannot move further than this

I want to hide my toolbar too if i scroll further.

Comment: post your xml code !!

Comment: how are you using `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` within your root layout ? make your parent layout also as `coordinator layout` .. !!

Comment: So If I scroll further I want to hide my main toolbar too.

Comment: ya just do this modification remove `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` from your upper toolbar and make the root layout as `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and you are good to go... ( **make these two changes** )

Comment: If you want to hide your toolbar too, then add your toolbar in coordinator layout too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your root layout needs to be a `CoordinatorLayout`.

Check out the *cheesesquare* sample project on [Github](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) for the exact details.